# Glob Syntax: Breadth first traversal to get all items in a folder using Karma

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, glob

I'm writing Karma to test some AngularJS code. In order for the tests to run correctly, certain modules have to be run before others. Controllers and services come after the module instantiation.

The way my code is structured right now (grossly simplified) is I have an "app" folder which contains another folder called "controllers".

Inside "app", I have an app.js file. Inside "app/controllers", I have someController.js.

```
/root 
    --- /app
           --- app.js
           --- /controllers
               --- someController.js
```

I'm using Karma to load all my files before I run tests. The tests are loaded after the source (app) files. But it's loading the source files in an order that's undesirable. It loads someController.js first before loading app.js. Probably because it does a depth-first traversal. I'm not looking for an algorithm or anything because that's all that Google seems to give me. Just a simple string glob pattern.

The syntax I'm using is "root/**/*.js" to get all the files in all sub-directories of "root".

How do I specify to Karma that I want to load all the files in "/app" before loading files in "app/controllers/"? (ie. breadth first traversal)

The example I'm following from Karma's documentation is here: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html under the Configure Karma section.

Specifically:

```
 files: [
      {pattern: 'lib/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},

      'test/test-main.js'
    ],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to explicitly control the traversal strategy of the globbing, but you can manually create multiple patterns which will force the desired order. If you use a simple `dir/*.js` pattern first, only the top level `.js` files will be matched, and then in a second pass you can go deeper with a more permissive `dir/**/*.js` pattern.

In your case, these patterns would be something like:

```
{pattern: 'app/*.js', included: false},
{pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false},
```

---

However, if you have several places where you need to specify the loading order, this can become cumbersome to maintain. For cases like this I found it very helpful to set up the build environment to generate the includes into the karma configuration file at the same time as generating the includes into the main `.html` file of the app - usually the same order restrictions apply to both. For example, if you're using something like `grunt-wiredep`, this can be as easy as adding a new target with a custom `fileTypes` entry to set up the proper syntax.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing: 'app/*.js' then 'app/**/*.js', but it is just as you said. I have many 'app' folders and many controllers/services inside those folders. I was looking into using RequireJS to specify the order in which they load, but their documentation is very difficult to understand. If I had a globbing pattern that does breadth-first traversal, it would solve my problem rather easily.

Comment: I am using Gulp.js as a task runner. I could look into finding some wiredep for Gulp, but that seems like it would be outside the scope of Gulp. Gulp just runs Karma, which already uses RequireJS. Using another extension of Gulp to configure Karma seems overly convoluted.

Comment: I missed the part where you mentioned Require - if you're using RequireJS, that should be taking care of the load order, not Karma. What does your require config (of test-main) look like?